# Calculating probability based on probability generating function

Tags: probability, solution-verification, generating-functions

Given a random variable X which is non-negative and integer valued and its corresponding probability generating function:
$$G_X(s) = e^{s-1}$$

Find: $$P(X<2)$$

As per my calculations I get the answer:
$$e^{0-1} + e^{1-1} = e^{-1} + e^{0} = e^{-1} + 1$$

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Showing some of your own effort will increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: I had accidentally added the wrong question. I have updated the details now. I have already tried solving it but I am wondering if my calculations are correct?

Comment: Notice that your result is greater than 1 and so cannot be a probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From elementary theory on Taylor series we know that the probability mass function of $X$ can be obtained by differentiating its probability generating function. That is, for each nonnegative integer $k$ we have
$$
p_k := \mathbb P(X=k) = \lim_{s\downarrow0}\frac{G_X^{(k)}(s)}{k!}.
$$
Since $\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf ds} G_X(s) = G_X(s)$, it follows that
$$
p_k = \frac{e^{-1}}{k!},
$$
and hence
$$
\mathbb P(X<2) = p_0 + p_1 = e^{-1}(1+1) = 2e^{-1}.
$$